# Symfony 2 : doctrine and associated entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have those 2 tables in my database :

```
REF_PARAM(id, label)
DECLARATION(number, status)
```

'status' is a foreign key to REF_PARAM.

I generate my entities with the command line. I have 2 entities RefParam and Declaration :

```
<?php

namespace Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Declaration
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="declaration")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cramif\AccueilBundle\Repository\DeclarationRepository")
*/
class Declaration
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="IDENTIFIANT", type="string", length=8, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $identifiant;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NOM_INTERLOCUTEUR", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $nomInterlocuteur;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="REFERENCE", type="string", length=14, nullable=true)
 */
private $reference;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DESCRIPTION", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="COMMENTAIRE", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $commentaire;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="AGENT_SAISIE_ID", type="string", length=6, nullable=true)
 */
private $agentSaisieId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="AGENT_SAISIE_NOM", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $agentSaisieNom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="AGENT_SAISIE_PRENOM", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $agentSaisiePrenom;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DATE_CREATION", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateCreation;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="AGENT_VALIDATION_ID", type="string", length=6, nullable=true)
 */
private $agentValidationId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="AGENT_VALIDATION_NOM", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $agentValidationNom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="AGENT_VALIDATION_PRENOM", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $agentValidationPrenom;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DATE_VALIDATION", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateValidation;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DATE_FERMETURE", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateFermeture;

/**
 * @var \RefParam
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RefParam")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="TRAITEMENT", referencedColumnName="ID")
 * })
 */
private $traitement;

/**
 * @var \RefParam
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RefParam")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="STATUT", referencedColumnName="ID")
 * })
 */
private $statut;

/**
 * @var \RefParam
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RefParam")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="STATUT_INTERLOCUTEUR", referencedColumnName="ID")
 * })
 */
private $statutInterlocuteur;



/**
 * Get identifiant
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getIdentifiant()
{
    return $this->identifiant;
}

/**
 * Get identifiant
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function setIdentifiant($identifiant)
{
    $this->identifiant = $identifiant;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set nomInterlocuteur
 *
 * @param string $nomInterlocuteur
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setNomInterlocuteur($nomInterlocuteur)
{
    $this->nomInterlocuteur = $nomInterlocuteur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nomInterlocuteur
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNomInterlocuteur()
{
    return $this->nomInterlocuteur;
}

/**
 * Set reference
 *
 * @param string $reference
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setReference($reference)
{
    $this->reference = $reference;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get reference
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getReference()
{
    return $this->reference;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set commentaire
 *
 * @param string $commentaire
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setCommentaire($commentaire)
{
    $this->commentaire = $commentaire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get commentaire
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCommentaire()
{
    return $this->commentaire;
}

/**
 * Set agentSaisieId
 *
 * @param string $agentSaisieId
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setAgentSaisieId($agentSaisieId)
{
    $this->agentSaisieId = $agentSaisieId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentSaisieId
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAgentSaisieId()
{
    return $this->agentSaisieId;
}

/**
 * Set agentSaisieNom
 *
 * @param string $agentSaisieNom
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setAgentSaisieNom($agentSaisieNom)
{
    $this->agentSaisieNom = $agentSaisieNom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentSaisieNom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAgentSaisieNom()
{
    return $this->agentSaisieNom;
}

/**
 * Set agentSaisiePrenom
 *
 * @param string $agentSaisiePrenom
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setAgentSaisiePrenom($agentSaisiePrenom)
{
    $this->agentSaisiePrenom = $agentSaisiePrenom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentSaisiePrenom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAgentSaisiePrenom()
{
    return $this->agentSaisiePrenom;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}

/**
 * Set agentValidationId
 *
 * @param string $agentValidationId
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setAgentValidationId($agentValidationId)
{
    $this->agentValidationId = $agentValidationId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentValidationId
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAgentValidationId()
{
    return $this->agentValidationId;
}

/**
 * Set agentValidationNom
 *
 * @param string $agentValidationNom
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setAgentValidationNom($agentValidationNom)
{
    $this->agentValidationNom = $agentValidationNom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentValidationNom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAgentValidationNom()
{
    return $this->agentValidationNom;
}

/**
 * Set agentValidationPrenom
 *
 * @param string $agentValidationPrenom
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setAgentValidationPrenom($agentValidationPrenom)
{
    $this->agentValidationPrenom = $agentValidationPrenom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentValidationPrenom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAgentValidationPrenom()
{
    return $this->agentValidationPrenom;
}

/**
 * Set dateValidation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateValidation
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setDateValidation($dateValidation)
{
    $this->dateValidation = $dateValidation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateValidation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateValidation()
{
    return $this->dateValidation;
}

/**
 * Set dateFermeture
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateFermeture
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setDateFermeture($dateFermeture)
{
    $this->dateFermeture = $dateFermeture;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateFermeture
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateFermeture()
{
    return $this->dateFermeture;
}

/**
 * Set traitement
 *
 * @param \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam $traitement
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setTraitement(\Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam $traitement = null)
{
    $this->traitement = $traitement;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get traitement
 *
 * @return \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam 
 */
public function getTraitement()
{
    return $this->traitement;
}

/**
 * Set statut
 *
 * @param \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam $statut
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setStatut(\Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam $statut = null)
{
    $this->statut = $statut;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get statut
 *
 * @return \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam 
 */
public function getStatut()
{
    return $this->statut;
}

/**
 * Set statutInterlocuteur
 *
 * @param \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam $statutInterlocuteur
 * @return Declaration
 */
public function setStatutInterlocuteur(\Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam $statutInterlocuteur = null)
{
    $this->statutInterlocuteur = $statutInterlocuteur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get statutInterlocuteur
 *
 * @return \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam 
 */
public function getStatutInterlocuteur()
{
    return $this->statutInterlocuteur;
}
```

}

---

```
namespace Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RefParam
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ref_param")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cramif\AccueilBundle\Repository\RefParamRepository")
 */
class RefParam
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="LIBELLE", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $libelle;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DATE_CREATION", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateCreation;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DATE_MODIFICATION", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateModification;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DATE_SUPPRESSION", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateSuppression;

/**
 * @var \RefCategorie
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RefCategorie")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ID_CATEGORIE", referencedColumnName="ID")
 * })
 */
private $idCategorie;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set libelle
 *
 * @param string $libelle
 * @return RefParam
 */
public function setLibelle($libelle)
{
    $this->libelle = $libelle;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get libelle
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLibelle()
{
    return $this->libelle;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 * @return RefParam
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}

/**
 * Set dateModification
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateModification
 * @return RefParam
 */
public function setDateModification($dateModification)
{
    $this->dateModification = $dateModification;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateModification
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateModification()
{
    return $this->dateModification;
}

/**
 * Set dateSuppression
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateSuppression
 * @return RefParam
 */
public function setDateSuppression($dateSuppression)
{
    $this->dateSuppression = $dateSuppression;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateSuppression
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateSuppression()
{
    return $this->dateSuppression;
}

/**
 * Set idCategorie
 *
 * @param \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefCategorie $idCategorie
 * @return RefParam
 */
public function setIdCategorie(\Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefCategorie $idCategorie = null)
{
    $this->idCategorie = $idCategorie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idCategorie
 *
 * @return \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefCategorie 
 */
public function getIdCategorie()
{
    return $this->idCategorie;
}
```

}

When persisting Declaration object, I have an exception :

```
A new entity was found that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity RefParam
```

Of course, I dont want to persist RefParam because all of the statuses are already in the database.
So, and I am not sure I am right, I thought about using the mappedBy property to say that I want to use the id of the RefParam when the Declaration is persisted in the DECLARATION table.
So I added :

```
/**
 * @var \RefParam
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RefParam", mappedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="STATUS", referencedColumnName="ID")
 * })
 */
```

I have another exception :

```
 The annotation @ORM\ManyToOne does not have a property named "mappedBy"
```

It looks it is more reversedBy that I can use with ManyToOne relations. It does not solve my problem.

Well my question is :

How do I persist the Declaration object and put the id of the RefParam object in the status column?

Thanks to you

---

PERSISTENCE

```
$declaration = new Declaration(); // this is not the entity class but a Model class I have
$declaration->setDeclarationForm($declaration_form); //declaration_form is the object the form is based on


$declaration->setDateCreation(new \DateTime());
$declaration->setAgentSaisie($session->get('agent'));
$declaration->setStatut(new Param(2));


$declaration_entity = DeclarationRepository::fromModelClass($declaration); // get the entity class Declaration from the model class I have

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($declaration_entity);
$em->flush();
```

---

Model to entity transformation

```
public static function fromModelClass(\Cramif\AccueilBundle\Model\Declaration $declaration) {
    $entity_declaration = new \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\Declaration();
    $entity_declaration->setIdentifiant($declaration->getDeclarationForm()->getIdentifiant());
    $entity_declaration->setNomInterlocuteur($declaration->getDeclarationForm()->getNomCible());
    $entity_declaration->setReference($declaration->getDeclarationForm()->getReference());
    $entity_declaration->setDescription($declaration->getDeclarationForm()->getDescription());
    $entity_declaration->setCommentaire($declaration->getDeclarationForm()->getCommentaire());
    $entity_declaration->setDateCreation($declaration->getDateCreation());
    $entity_declaration->setDateFermeture($declaration->getDateFermeture());
    $entity_declaration->setDateValidation($declaration->getDateValidation());
    $entity_declaration->setAgentSaisieId($declaration->getAgentSaisie()->getIdentifiant());
    $entity_declaration->setAgentSaisieNom($declaration->getAgentSaisie()->getNom());
    $entity_declaration->setAgentSaisiePrenom($declaration->getAgentSaisie()->getPrenom());

    if(is_object($declaration->getAgentValidation())) {
        $entity_declaration->setAgentValidationId($declaration->getAgentValidation()->getIdentifiant());
        $entity_declaration->setAgentValidationNom($declaration->getAgentValidation()->getNom());
        $entity_declaration->setAgentValidationPrenom($declaration->getAgentValidation()->getPrenom());
    }

    $refParamStatut = new \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam();
    $refParamStatut->setId($declaration->getStatut()->getId());
    $entity_declaration->setStatut($refParamStatut);

    $refParamTraitement = new \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam();
    $refParamTraitement->setId($declaration->getDeclarationForm()->getTraitement()->getId());
    $entity_declaration->setTraitement($refParamTraitement);

    $refParamStatutInterlocuteur = new \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam();
    $refParamStatutInterlocuteur->setId($declaration->getDeclarationForm()->getQualiteInterlocuteur()->getId());
    $entity_declaration->setStatutInterlocuteur($refParamStatutInterlocuteur);

    return $entity_declaration;
```

Comment: You should only need `mappedBy` for OneToMany relationships (where it indicates the field in which the foreign key is stored on the "Many" side), and you only need `inversedBy` for Bi-directional relationships (e.g. you want to be able to find all the Declarations a particular RefParam has).  I would not expect to have seen that error message for a simple ManyToOne, as you say it should be OK to `$declaration->setStatus(null)`, for example.  Have you got any other Associations configured on RefParam?

Comment: Could we see your persistence code and the full entities?

Comment: absolutly... In Declaration.php I have three properties which are RefParam objects

Comment: can I use mappedBy in RefParam class saying that it refers to several properties in Declaration or else where ? it would be strange to do that

Comment: I'm sure you can do that, quite reasonable to have multiple associations to the same entity with different meanings.  I've not done it though.  Could you add the code where the actual persistence happens?

Comment: What is `Param`'s relationship with `RefParam`?

Comment: none.. this is a model class with id and label only

Comment: But at some point you turn the `Param` into a `RefParam` (at the same time as you turn the `Declaration Model` into a `Declaration Entity`)?  Is `DeclarationRepository::fromModelClass($declaration)` your own code, could we see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line in `fromModelClass` when you get the `RefParam` object:

```
$refParamStatut = new \Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\RefParam();
```

From Doctrine's perspective `statut` is being set to a brand new object, never seen before.  When you persist `$declaration_entity` it knows that its `RefParam` is an Entity but not one in the DB, so it complains.  You either need to persist it yourself, or have persists cascade so Doctrine does it for you, or, and this is probably the answer in your case because you don't want to make any new `RefParam`s, fetch the right `RefParam` object from the DB in the first place (and then it won't need persisting at all).

e.g.

*fromModelClass*

```
$refParamStatut = $paramRepository->find($declaration->getStatut()->getId());
```

*Persistence* (NB now unchanged from your example, since $declaration->refParamStatut is a managed Entity)

```
$param = new Param(2); //POPO model
$declaration->setStatut($param);

//Within fromModelClass $param gets turned into a managed RefParam Entity, which doesn't need persisting
$declaration_entity = DeclarationRepository::fromModelClass($declaration);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($declaration_entity);
$em->flush(); //No exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigning new Object in line:

```
$declaration->setStatut(new Param(2));
```

which is not managed by Doctrine, that's why it want to persist it.

Instead of using one fetched from DB you can set reference:

```
$declaration->setStatut($em->getReference('App\AcmeBUndle\Entity\Param', 2));
```